# Running controller POST method from typescript/angular

Tags: angular, typescript, post

I have created the project (Angular/Typescript at FrontEnd, C# Controllers at Backend).

While I could run GET methods via:

```
http.get(originUrl + '/api/Poker/GetPokerValues').subscribe(result => {
            this.pokerValues = result.json() as PokerValue[];
});
```

to execute backend method:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IEnumerable<PokerValue> GetPokerValues()
{ //this code does execute
            return List;
}
```

I am still not able to run POST method via (Typescript) code:

```
var url = this._originUrl + '/api/Poker/SetPokerValue';
        this._http.post(url, dataToPass, {
            headers: headers
}).map(response => response.json());
```

at the controller:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public ActionResult SetPokerValue(string someVar)
{//this code does not execute
    return Json("Success");
}
```

Do you have any idea what I did wrong to make it work?

Here is my code:
https://github.com/kamilhawdziejuk/Scrum/blob/master/Angular/Controllers/PokerController.cs

https://github.com/kamilhawdziejuk/Scrum/blob/master/Angular/ClientApp/app/components/poker/poker.component.ts

Comment: `.map` doesn't subscribe to the stream, so the request is never made. You should subscribe somewhere, either in the service or by returning the observable and subscribing in the consumer.

Comment: Thanks. This helped.